# Can't Get Angular To Load Routes

Tags: html, css, angularjs, django, ngroute

I am making a local page following this [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#registering-new-users), and it implements a login using django and angular. But I can't get the button **register** to show anything. It just changes the directory to /register. I think it has to do with routing. I get no errors. And I don't know how to debug this thing anymore, so I've run out of options. This is my first 'website'.

Reason this isn't going smooth is because I did not get the starter project the tutorial came with. I wanted to learn how to implement this from scratch. This means my packages are newer (bootstrap, django, etc). Let me know if you need any more info, please. Thanks.

/templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="hawk">

<head>
  <title>Hawk</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  {% include 'navbar.html' %}

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 ng-view"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  {% include 'javascripts.html' %}
</body>

</html>
```

/static/javascripts/hawk.routes.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hawk.routes')
        .config(config);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    function config($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/register', {
            controller: 'RegisterController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: '/static/templates/authentication/register.html'
        }).otherwise('/');
    }
})();
```

/static/javascripts/authentication/controllers/register.controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hawk.authentication.controllers')
        .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

    RegisterController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];

    function RegisterController($location, $scope, Authentication) {
        var vm = this;
        console.log("\n\nregister\n\n");
        vm.register = register;

        function register() {
            Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password, vm.username);
        }
    }
})();
```

/static/javascripts/hawk.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('hawk', [
      'hawk.routes',
      'hawk.authentication',
      'hawk.config',
    ]);

  angular
    .module('hawk.routes', [require('angular-route')]);
  angular
    .module('hawk.config', []);
  angular
    .module('hawk')
    .run(run);
  run.$inject = ['$http'];

  function run($http) {
    $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
  }
})();
```

/templates/javascripts.html

```
{% load compress %} {% load staticfiles %} {% compress js %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/js/ripples.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../node_modules/underscore/underscore.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../node_modules/angular/angular.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../node_modules/ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'lib/snackbarjs/snackbar.min.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/hawk.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/hawk.config.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/hawk.routes.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/authentication/authentication.module.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/authentication/services/authentication.service.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/authentication/controllers/register.controller.js' %}"></script> 
{% endcompress %}
```

/static/javascripts/authentication/services/authentication.service.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('hawk.authentication.services')
        .factory('Authentication', Authentication);
    Authentication.$inject = ['$cookies', '$http'];

    function Authentication($cookies, $http) {
        var Authentication = {
            register: register
        };

        return Authentication;

        function register(email, password, username) {
            return $http.post('/api/v1/accounts/', {
                username: username,
                password: password,
                email: email
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

/HawkProject/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from rest_framework_nested import routers
from authentication.views import AccountViewSet
from HawkProject.views import IndexView

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),

    re_path(r'^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

Comment: Can you change `<div class="col-xs-12 ng-view"></div>` to `<div class="col-xs-12"><section ng-view></section></div>` and let me if it worked\

Comment: it didn't. thanks tho.

Comment: can you confirm whether you can see `console.log` inside the `RegisterController`  when the path is clicked using button?

Comment: I do not see it! ( i added the line to answer above to reflect change)

Comment: cool,**so your routing is not getting called at all**. do you still have the my suggested edit of `<div class="col-xs-12"><section ng-view></section></div>` while checking `console.log`. If not, do so. You cant add `ng-view` as a class, that is wrong

Comment: yea, i still have it as you say. (Weird the tutorial has it the wrong way in the starter download)

Comment: yes I have added the files. I think those are it.

Comment: Ok, you can remove that file as it does not have that logic. Where are you calling `route` using `$location.path( "/register" );`?

Comment: I do search for "path( "/register"" and I don't find it. I only see /register in javascripts.html, navbar.html, and hawk.routes.js. I added urls.py  since it calls router.register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Although its not an answer to this question precisely but its an answer with a diff approach**

The tutorial you have provided is too long and not included with video. I have worked on `Django` and `AngularJS` to create an ecommerce website. I'l suggest you not to mix `Django` and `AngularJS` as much as you can to avoid conflicts. That being said, I'll provide you what I implemented for `User Registration` in brief:

1. I kept User form separate from AngularJS forms because Django has its own way to handle User Management (Sign in,sign Up, session (using `@login_required`) etc).
2. I provided `<a href="/sign_up">Register</a>` on the nav-bar. (**Note:** `/signup` is a url mapped in `urls.py` file)

   ```
       <form name="regForm" class="form-signup" action="/sign_up/" method="post" role="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
           {% csrf_token %}
           {{form.errors.values.0}}
           <div class="form-group reg-username" id="fname">
               <div>
                   <input name="first_name" class="form-control input" size="20" placeholder="Enter First Name" type="text" required>
               </div>
               <p id="fname-error" class="help-block"></p>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group reg-username">
               <div>
                   <input name="last_name" class="form-control input" size="20" placeholder="Enter Last Name" type="text" required>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group reg-email">
               <div>
                   <input name="email" class="form-control input" placeholder="Enter Email" type="email" required>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group reg-password" id="pwd1">
               <div>
                   <input name="password1" class="form-control input" placeholder="Password" type="password" required>
               </div>
               <p id="pwd-error1" class="help-block"></p>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group reg-password" id="pwd2">
               <div>
                   <input name="password2" class="form-control input" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" required>
               </div>
               <p id="pwd-error2" class="help-block"></p>
           </div>
           <input name="submit" class="btn  btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" value="REGISTER" type="submit">

       </form>
   ```

Where `url(r'^sign_up/', ('ecommerce.views.register_user')),`

In the **views.py**

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@csrf_protect
@requires_csrf_token
def register_user(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if not verify_google_recaptcha(request.POST):
            return HttpResponse(get_status_response('Failure', 'Are you sure you are not a robot?'))
        else:
            logger.info('Recaptcha passed !!!')

        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        msg = 'register'
        args['form'] = form

        if form.is_valid():

            try:
                # username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                email_obj ={}
                email_obj['email'] = form.cleaned_data['email']
                email_obj['first_name'] = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                email_obj['last_name'] = form.cleaned_data['last_name']

                salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
                activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salt + email_obj['email']).hexdigest()

                email_obj['activation_link'] = ACTIVATION_LINK.format(activation_key)

                template = get_template('RegistrationLink.html')
                context = Context({'email': email_obj})
                content = template.render(context)

                emsg = EmailMultiAlternatives('Activation link for {0}'.format(DEFAULT_DOMAIN) , content, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, to=[email_obj['email']])

                emsg.attach_alternative(content, "text/html")
                emsg.send()

                form.save()  # save user to database if form is valid

                # Get user by username
                user = SiteUser.objects.get(email=email_obj['email'])

                # Create and save user profile
                new_profile = UserProfile(user=user, activation_key=activation_key,
                                          key_expires=settings.EXPIRATION_DAYS)
                new_profile.save()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception(e)
                return render_to_response('500.html')

            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/register_success')
            return render_to_response('confirm.html', {'msg': msg})
    else:
        args['form'] = RegistrationForm()

    return render_to_response('userRegistration.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

> Note: The code written in `def register_user` is core Djnago feature to handle user registration which I am exploiting. You can get these over internet

3. If you need to render any `form` such as `Order address`, then create a form of angular and simple pass the value to `Django` using `$http` (the `/url_called` from `$http` will be mapped in `urls.py`).
4. Make sure you are using `{% verbatim %}` and `{% endverbatim %}` whenever you are using `{{ some_angular_variable }} because it contradicts with`Django Template`syntax. Better to go for`ng-bind` as much as you can.
5. Ignore `$locationProvider` for now if you are in initial stage. You'll get some issues when using that with `Django`. I have a solution for that as well but for beginner, dont get into that. Try to integrate the [plunkr code](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/uUE1gx) in your Django app and see if it's working. Start small, dont jump to complicated examples.

> [Check one basic example of ngRoute](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/uUE1gx).

**In case you get stuck, post another question and put the link in the comment so that I can help you in that as well**

Comment: you are probably right. I shouldn't start so complicated.